# Read complex numbers (a+bi) from text file in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

i want to read an array of complex numbers (in `a+bi` form). There are several suggestions I found on the internet, however those methods only result the `real part`, while the `imaginary part` is always `0`. And infact the `real part` of the next number is the `imaginary` of the previous number.

For example, I have an text file as follow:

```
2+4i
1+5i
7+6i
```

And here is a suggestion for reading complex data

```
int nRow = 3;
std::complex<int> c;
std::ifstream fin("test.txt");
std::string line;
std::vector<std::complex<int> > vec;
vec.reserve(nRow);
while (std::getline(fin, line))
{
    std::stringstream stream(line);
    while (stream >> c)
    {
        vec.push_back(c);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++){
    cout << vec[i].real() << "\t" << vec[i].imag() << endl;
}

while (1);
return 0;
```

And the output result is:

```
2   0
4   0
1   0
```

Is there a proper way to read `a+bi` complex numbers from text file? Or do I have to read the data as a string, and then process the string to extract and convert it back to complex numer?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried using fscanf()?

Comment: Note that if you have control over the text format, `<complex>` already provides an `operator>>` and `operator<<` to read/write in the format `(re,im)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to read separately the real and imaginary part in 2 `int`s, and the sign into a `char`, then `emplace_back` into the complex vector, like

```
int re, im;
char sign;
while (stream >> re >> sign >> im)
{
    vec.emplace_back(re, (sign == '-') ? -im : im);
}
```

Here `sign` is a `char` variable that "eats" up the sign.

Comment: what if the `junk` is minus?

Comment: @simplicisveritatis Then you need to process it ;) This was an over simplified example. Will edit the answer though, thanks.

Comment: that's a whole new line including an `if` statement and a comparison :)

Comment: @simplicisveritatis Wrote it into one line so I deserve the upvote ;)

Comment: I think I'd reverse the logic, so it treats *only* `-` as meaning negation, and anything as meaning `+` (e.g., so `1, 2i` would be read correctly).

Comment: @JerryCoffin You're right, edited. That's how it was originally (with the `if` statement before edit).

Answer (score 2):

```
FILE *fp;
char line[80];
int a, b;

if ((fp = fopen("filename", "r") != NULL)
    while (fgets(line, 80, fp) != NULL) {
        if (sscanf(line, "%d + %di", &a, &b) == 2)
            /* do something with a and b */
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Not in a+bi form");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement (the format of input you seek) does not correspond to the method you are using to read it.    The default streaming of a complex is the real and the imaginary part separated by spaces and in brackets - the sign between is not mandatory, and the trailing `i` is not required.

The obvious way to parse for input you seek is to read the real part, read a character, check if the character is a signed (`+` or `-`) and ignore spaces, then read the imaginary part.   That is trivial with `istream`s.

Comment: thank @Peter. You're right, the format was not suitable for the method I used. I'll look at {istream} function. By the way, I think the above answer from vsoftco may use a similar method like your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
int real[10] = { 0 };
int imaginary[10] = { 0 };
FILE *lpFile = fopen("filename" "rt"); // Open the file
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fscanf(lpFile, "%d+%di", &real[i], &imaginary[i]); // Read data 10 times
}
fclose(lpFile); // Close the file
```

This example code will read 10 complex numbers from a file.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Jerry Coffin's comment (Jan 5, 2016), perhaps the easiest method of entering complex numbers is shown in the following:

```
// test_input.cpp
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main( void ) {

    std::complex<double> a, b;
    std::cout << "Enter two complex numbers: ";
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << "a + b = " <<  a + b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a - b = " <<  a - b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a * b = " <<  a * b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a / b = " <<  a / b << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "Re part of a = " << real( a ) << endl;
    std::cout << "Im part of a = " << imag( a ) << endl;
    std::cout << "Re part of b = " << real( b ) << endl;
    std::cout << "Im part of b = " << imag( b ) << endl;
   
    return 0;
}
g++ -std=c++14 -o test_input test_input.cpp
./test_input
Enter two complex numbers: 2 (1,2)
a + b = (3,2)
a - b = (1,-2)
a * b = (2,4)
a / b = (0.4,-0.8)
Re part of a = 2
Im part of a = 0
Re part of b = 1
Im part of b = 2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).