# How to read imaginary data from text file, with C

Tags: c, text, complex.h

I am unable to read imaginary data from text file.
Here is my .txt file

> abc.txt

```
0.2e-3+0.3*I   0.1+0.1*I
0.3+0.1*I      0.1+0.4*I
```

I want to read this data into a *matrix* and print it.

I found the solutions using *C++* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57967046/c-read-in-complex-numbers-from-a-txt-file-and-store-into-an-array-of-complex) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622309/read-complex-numbers-abi-from-text-file-in-c). I don't know how to do the same in C.

I am able to read decimal and integer data in .txt and print them.
I am also able to print imaginary data initialized at the declaration, using `complex.h` header. This is the program I have writtern

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<complex.h>
#include<math.h>
int M,N,i,j,k,l,p,q;
int b[2];
int main(void)
{
    FILE* ptr = fopen("abc.txt", "r");
        if (ptr == NULL) {
            printf("no such file.");
            return 0;
        }
    long double d=0.2e-3+0.3*I;
    long double c=0.0000000600415046630252;
    double matrixA[2][2];
    for(i=0;i<2; i++)
        for(j=0;j<2; j++)
            fscanf(ptr,"%lf+i%lf\n", creal(&matrixA[i][j]), cimag(&matrixA[i][j])); 
            //fscanf(ptr, "%lf", &matrixA[i][j]) for reading non-imainary data, It worked. 

    for(i=0;i<2; i++)
            for(j=0;j<2; j++)
                printf("%f+i%f\n", creal(matrixA[i][j]), cimag(matrixA[i][j]));
              //printf("%lf\n", matrixA[i][j]);  for printing non-imainary data, It worked. 

    printf("%f+i%f\n", creal(d), cimag(d));
    printf("%Lg\n",c);

    fclose(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

But I want to read it from the text, because I have an array of larger size, which I can't initialize at declaration, because of it's size.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "don't know how". Please show what you have tried as a [mre] and describe what specific step you are stuck on.

Comment: `fscanf` is probably the first function to try in order to find a solution.

Comment: You print spaces around the `+` sign that are not present in the input format.  Do we need to cope with your output format as well as the input format?  And presumably you can have `-1.2-3.6*I` (with a `-` instead of `+`)?  Ensuring that the `*I` was present and read presents some issues, but they are not insurmountable.  What have you tried, and where do you run into problems?

Comment: I have put the Minimal, Reproducible Example code I have used. As per the `+` or `-` sign in `printf` statement. I used only `+` symbol. I have not checked the implications of `-` sign. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Your code doesn't check the return value from `fscanf()` so you've no idea what worked.  Your format contains `%lf+i%lf` which bears no relation to the example inputs such as `0.2e-3+0.3*I`,

Comment: Note [the effect of trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19499060/15168)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues with your code:

- You need to add `complex` to the variables that hold complex values.
- `scanf()` needs *pointers* to objects to store scanned values in them. But `creal()` returns a value, copied from its argument's contents. It is neither a pointer, nor could you get the address of the corresponding part of the complex argument.

Therefore, you need to provide temporary objects to `scanf()` which receive the scanned values. After successfully scanning, these values are combined to a complex value and assigned to the indexed matrix cell.

Minor issues not contributing to the core problem are:

- The given source is "augmented" with unneeded `#include`s, unused variables, global variables, and experiments with constants. I removed them all to see the real thing.
- The specifier `"%f"` (as many others) lets `scanf()` skip whitespace like blanks, tabs, newlines, and so on. Providing a `"\n"` mostly does more harm than one would expect.

  I kept the `"*I"` to check the correct format. However, an error will only be found on the next call of `scanf()`, when it cannot scan the next number.
- You need to check the return value of `scanf()`, always! It returns the number of conversions that were successful.
- It is a common and good habit to let the compiler calculate the number of elements in an array. Divide the total size by an element's size.

  Oh, and `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.
- It is also best to return symbolic values to the caller, instead of magic numbers. Fortunately, the standard library defines these `EXIT_...` macros.
- The signs are correctly handled by `scanf()` already. There is no need to tell it more. But for a nice output with `printf()`, you use the `"+"` as a flag to always output a sign.
- Since the sign is now placed directly before the number, I moved the multiplication by `I` (you can change it to lower case, if you want) to the back of the imaginary part. This also matches the input format.
- Error output is done via `stderr` instead of `stdout`. For example, this enables you to redirect the standard output to a pipe or file, without missing potential errors. You can also redirect errors somewhere else. And it is a well-known and appreciated standard.

This is a possible solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* ptr = fopen("abc.txt", "r");
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        perror("\"abc.txt\"");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    double complex matrixA[2][2];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof matrixA / sizeof matrixA[0]; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof matrixA[0] / sizeof matrixA[0][0]; j++) {
            double real;
            double imag;
            if (fscanf(ptr, "%lf%lf*I", &real, &imag) != 2) {
                fclose(ptr);
                fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input format\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            matrixA[i][j] = real + imag * I;
        }

    fclose(ptr);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof matrixA / sizeof matrixA[0]; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof matrixA[0] / sizeof matrixA[0][0]; j++)
            printf("%+f%+f*I\n", creal(matrixA[i][j]), cimag(matrixA[i][j]));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @the-busybuy. It works well, even for using small `i` instead of `I`. The only place we need to use `I` is in the _for loop_. `matrixA[i][j] = real + imag * I;`. Otherwise it gives invalid input format. Thank you so much.

Comment: Well, you have it in your example input. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using `scanf()` and the format shown in the examples.
It writes the values in the same format that it reads them — the output can be scanned by the program as input.

```c
/* SO 7438-4793 */
#include <stdio.h>

static int read_complex(FILE *fp, double *r, double *i)
{
    int offset = 0;
    char sign[2];
    if (fscanf(fp, "%lg%[-+]%lg*%*[iI]%n", r, sign, i, &offset) != 3 || offset == 0)
        return EOF;
    if (sign[0] == '-')
        *i = -*i;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    double r;
    double i;

    while (read_complex(stdin, &r, &i) == 0)
        printf("%g%+g*I\n", r, i);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

```
0.2e-3+0.3*I   0.1+0.1*I
0.3+0.1*I      0.1+0.4*I
-1.2-3.6*I     -6.02214076e23-6.62607015E-34*I
```

Output from sample input:

```
0.0002+0.3*I
0.1+0.1*I
0.3+0.1*I
0.1+0.4*I
-1.2-3.6*I
-6.02214e+23-6.62607e-34*I
```

The numbers at the end with large exponents are Avogadro's Number and the Planck Constant.

The format is about as stringent are you can make it with `scanf()`, but, although it requires a sign (`+` or `-`) between the real and imaginary parts and requires the `*` and `I` to be immediately after the imaginary part (and the conversion will fail if the `*I` is missing), and accepts either `i` or `I` to indicate the imaginary value:

- It doesn't stop the imaginary number having a second sign (so it will read a value such as "`-6+-4*I`").
- It doesn't stop there being white space after the mandatory sign (so it will read a value such as "`-6+  24*I`".
- It doesn't stop the real part being on one line and the imaginary part on the next line.
- It won't handle either a pure-real number or a pure-imaginary number properly.

The `scanf()` functions are very flexible about white space, and it is very hard to prevent them from accepting white space.  It would require a custom parser to prevent unwanted spaces.  You could do that by reading the numbers and the markers separately, as strings, and then verifying that there's no space and so on.  That might be the best way to handle it.  You'd use `sscanf()` to convert the string read after ensuring there's no embedded white space yet the format is correct.

---

> I do not know which IDE you are using for C, so I do not understand this `./testprog <test.data`.

I have yet to find an IDE that does not drive me bonkers.  I use a Unix shell running in a terminal window.  Assuming that your program name is `testprog` and the data file is `test.data`, typing `./testprog < test.data` runs the program and feeds the contents of `test.data` as its standard input.  On Windows, this would be a command window (and I think PowerShell would work much the same way).

> I used `fgets` to read each line of the text file. Though I know the functionality of `sscanf`, I do not know how to parse an entire line, which has about 23 elements per line. If the number of elements in a line are few, I know how to parse it. Could you help me about it?

As I noted in a comment, the SO Q&A [How to use `sscanf()` in loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops) explains how to use `sscanf()` to read multiple entries from a line.  In this case, you will need to read multiple complex numbers from a single line.  Here is some code that shows it at work.  It uses the POSIX [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function to read arbitrarily long lines.  If it isn't available to you, you can use `fgets()` instead, but you'll need to preallocate a big enough line buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>

#ifndef CMPLX
#define CMPLX(r, i)     ((double complex)((double)(r) + I * (double)(i)))
#endif

static size_t scan_multi_complex(const char *string, size_t nvalues,
                                 complex double *v, const char **eoc)
{
    size_t nread = 0;
    const char *buffer = string;
    while (nread < nvalues)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        char sign[2];
        double r, i;
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%lg%[-+]%lg*%*[iI]%n", &r, sign, &i, &offset) != 3 || offset == 0)
            break;
        if (sign[0] == '-')
            i = -i;
        v[nread++] = CMPLX(r, i);
        buffer += offset;
    }

    *eoc = buffer;
    return nread;
}

static void dump_complex(size_t nvalues, complex double values[nvalues])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nvalues; i++)
        printf("%g%+g*I\n", creal(values[i]), cimag(values[i]));
}

enum { NUM_VALUES = 128 };

int main(void)
{
    double complex values[NUM_VALUES];
    size_t nvalues = 0;
    char *buffer = 0;
    size_t buflen = 0;
    int length;
    size_t lineno = 0;

    while ((length = getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin)) > 0 && nvalues < NUM_VALUES)
    {
        const char *eoc;
        printf("Line: %zu [[%.*s]]\n", ++lineno, length - 1, buffer);
        size_t nread = scan_multi_complex(buffer, NUM_VALUES - nvalues, &values[nvalues], &eoc);
        if (*eoc != '\0' && *eoc != '\n')
            printf("EOC:  [[%s]]\n", eoc);
        if (nread == 0)
            break;
        dump_complex(nread, &values[nvalues]);
        nvalues += nread;
    }
    free(buffer);

    printf("All done:\n");
    dump_complex(nvalues, values);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a data file with 8 lines with 10 complex numbers per line):

```
-1.95+11.00*I +21.72+64.12*I -95.16-1.81*I +64.23+64.55*I +28.42-29.29*I -49.25+7.87*I +44.98+79.62*I +69.80-1.24*I +61.99+37.01*I +72.43+56.88*I
-9.15+31.41*I +63.84-15.82*I -0.77-76.80*I -85.59+74.86*I +93.00-35.10*I -93.82+52.80*I +85.45+82.42*I +0.67-55.77*I -58.32+72.63*I -27.66-81.15*I
+87.97+9.03*I +7.05-74.91*I +27.60+65.89*I +49.81+25.08*I +44.33+77.00*I +93.27-7.74*I +61.62-5.01*I +99.33-82.80*I +8.83+62.96*I +7.45+73.70*I
+40.99-12.44*I +53.34+21.74*I +75.77-62.56*I +54.16-26.97*I -37.02-31.93*I +78.20-20.91*I +79.64+74.71*I +67.95-40.73*I +58.19+61.25*I +62.29-22.43*I
+47.36-16.19*I +68.48-15.00*I +6.85+61.50*I -6.62+55.18*I +34.95-69.81*I -88.62-81.15*I +75.92-74.65*I +85.17-3.84*I -37.20-96.98*I +74.97+78.88*I
+56.80+63.63*I +92.83-16.18*I -11.47+8.81*I +90.74+42.86*I +19.11-56.70*I -77.93-70.47*I +6.73+86.12*I +2.70-57.93*I +57.87+29.44*I +6.65-63.09*I
-35.35-70.67*I +8.08-21.82*I +86.72-93.82*I -28.96-24.69*I +68.73-15.36*I +52.85+94.65*I +85.07-84.04*I +9.98+29.56*I -78.01-81.23*I -10.67+13.68*I
+83.10-33.86*I +56.87+30.23*I -78.56+3.73*I +31.41+10.30*I +91.98+29.04*I -9.20+24.59*I +70.82-19.41*I +29.21+84.74*I +56.62+92.29*I +70.66-48.35*I
```

The output of the program is:

```
Line: 1 [[-1.95+11.00*I +21.72+64.12*I -95.16-1.81*I +64.23+64.55*I +28.42-29.29*I -49.25+7.87*I +44.98+79.62*I +69.80-1.24*I +61.99+37.01*I +72.43+56.88*I]]
-1.95+11*I
21.72+64.12*I
-95.16-1.81*I
64.23+64.55*I
28.42-29.29*I
-49.25+7.87*I
44.98+79.62*I
69.8-1.24*I
61.99+37.01*I
72.43+56.88*I
Line: 2 [[-9.15+31.41*I +63.84-15.82*I -0.77-76.80*I -85.59+74.86*I +93.00-35.10*I -93.82+52.80*I +85.45+82.42*I +0.67-55.77*I -58.32+72.63*I -27.66-81.15*I]]
-9.15+31.41*I
63.84-15.82*I
-0.77-76.8*I
-85.59+74.86*I
93-35.1*I
-93.82+52.8*I
85.45+82.42*I
0.67-55.77*I
-58.32+72.63*I
-27.66-81.15*I
Line: 3 [[+87.97+9.03*I +7.05-74.91*I +27.60+65.89*I +49.81+25.08*I +44.33+77.00*I +93.27-7.74*I +61.62-5.01*I +99.33-82.80*I +8.83+62.96*I +7.45+73.70*I]]
87.97+9.03*I
7.05-74.91*I
27.6+65.89*I
49.81+25.08*I
44.33+77*I
93.27-7.74*I
61.62-5.01*I
99.33-82.8*I
8.83+62.96*I
7.45+73.7*I
Line: 4 [[+40.99-12.44*I +53.34+21.74*I +75.77-62.56*I +54.16-26.97*I -37.02-31.93*I +78.20-20.91*I +79.64+74.71*I +67.95-40.73*I +58.19+61.25*I +62.29-22.43*I]]
40.99-12.44*I
53.34+21.74*I
75.77-62.56*I
54.16-26.97*I
-37.02-31.93*I
78.2-20.91*I
79.64+74.71*I
67.95-40.73*I
58.19+61.25*I
62.29-22.43*I
Line: 5 [[+47.36-16.19*I +68.48-15.00*I +6.85+61.50*I -6.62+55.18*I +34.95-69.81*I -88.62-81.15*I +75.92-74.65*I +85.17-3.84*I -37.20-96.98*I +74.97+78.88*I]]
47.36-16.19*I
68.48-15*I
6.85+61.5*I
-6.62+55.18*I
34.95-69.81*I
-88.62-81.15*I
75.92-74.65*I
85.17-3.84*I
-37.2-96.98*I
74.97+78.88*I
Line: 6 [[+56.80+63.63*I +92.83-16.18*I -11.47+8.81*I +90.74+42.86*I +19.11-56.70*I -77.93-70.47*I +6.73+86.12*I +2.70-57.93*I +57.87+29.44*I +6.65-63.09*I]]
56.8+63.63*I
92.83-16.18*I
-11.47+8.81*I
90.74+42.86*I
19.11-56.7*I
-77.93-70.47*I
6.73+86.12*I
2.7-57.93*I
57.87+29.44*I
6.65-63.09*I
Line: 7 [[-35.35-70.67*I +8.08-21.82*I +86.72-93.82*I -28.96-24.69*I +68.73-15.36*I +52.85+94.65*I +85.07-84.04*I +9.98+29.56*I -78.01-81.23*I -10.67+13.68*I]]
-35.35-70.67*I
8.08-21.82*I
86.72-93.82*I
-28.96-24.69*I
68.73-15.36*I
52.85+94.65*I
85.07-84.04*I
9.98+29.56*I
-78.01-81.23*I
-10.67+13.68*I
Line: 8 [[+83.10-33.86*I +56.87+30.23*I -78.56+3.73*I +31.41+10.30*I +91.98+29.04*I -9.20+24.59*I +70.82-19.41*I +29.21+84.74*I +56.62+92.29*I +70.66-48.35*I]]
83.1-33.86*I
56.87+30.23*I
-78.56+3.73*I
31.41+10.3*I
91.98+29.04*I
-9.2+24.59*I
70.82-19.41*I
29.21+84.74*I
56.62+92.29*I
70.66-48.35*I
All done:
-1.95+11*I
21.72+64.12*I
-95.16-1.81*I
64.23+64.55*I
28.42-29.29*I
-49.25+7.87*I
44.98+79.62*I
69.8-1.24*I
61.99+37.01*I
72.43+56.88*I
-9.15+31.41*I
63.84-15.82*I
-0.77-76.8*I
-85.59+74.86*I
93-35.1*I
-93.82+52.8*I
85.45+82.42*I
0.67-55.77*I
-58.32+72.63*I
-27.66-81.15*I
87.97+9.03*I
7.05-74.91*I
27.6+65.89*I
49.81+25.08*I
44.33+77*I
93.27-7.74*I
61.62-5.01*I
99.33-82.8*I
8.83+62.96*I
7.45+73.7*I
40.99-12.44*I
53.34+21.74*I
75.77-62.56*I
54.16-26.97*I
-37.02-31.93*I
78.2-20.91*I
79.64+74.71*I
67.95-40.73*I
58.19+61.25*I
62.29-22.43*I
47.36-16.19*I
68.48-15*I
6.85+61.5*I
-6.62+55.18*I
34.95-69.81*I
-88.62-81.15*I
75.92-74.65*I
85.17-3.84*I
-37.2-96.98*I
74.97+78.88*I
56.8+63.63*I
92.83-16.18*I
-11.47+8.81*I
90.74+42.86*I
19.11-56.7*I
-77.93-70.47*I
6.73+86.12*I
2.7-57.93*I
57.87+29.44*I
6.65-63.09*I
-35.35-70.67*I
8.08-21.82*I
86.72-93.82*I
-28.96-24.69*I
68.73-15.36*I
52.85+94.65*I
85.07-84.04*I
9.98+29.56*I
-78.01-81.23*I
-10.67+13.68*I
83.1-33.86*I
56.87+30.23*I
-78.56+3.73*I
31.41+10.3*I
91.98+29.04*I
-9.2+24.59*I
70.82-19.41*I
29.21+84.74*I
56.62+92.29*I
70.66-48.35*I
```

The code would handle lines with any number of entries on a line (up to 128 in total because of the limit on the size of the array of complex numbers — but that can be fixed too.

Comment: Thanks @jonathan-Leffer. But it is printing upto 5 outputs at a time, in CCS.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about printing up to 5 outputs at a time.

Comment: What I meant is I have a text file with many elements. I can't put every element through keyboard. I tried copy, pasting all the elements at a time, but it is printing only the first five elements.

Comment: There must be a problem with the sixth entry in the file.  The code shown reads from standard input; it is a routine exercise to make it read from other files.  Indeed, the scanning function already reads from any open input file stream.  I was using `./testprog <test.data` to read from the file shown.  You might be better off reading whole lines from a file and then using `sscanf()` in a loop to parse the line.  You can do better error reporting that way.

Comment: Thansk @Jonathan-Leffler. I used `fgets` to read each line of the text file. Though I know the functionality of `sscanf`, I do not know how to parse an entire line, which has about 23 elements per line. If the number of elements in a line are few, I know how to parse it. Could you help me about it? . Also I do not know which which IDE you are using for C. SO I do not understand where is this `./testprog <test.data`

Comment: Here is the code I have used to get the line using `gets` [to read a line from a text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E5pyJRLVRSFISJOJgZt9v4LdYon2iksq/view?usp=sharing). I don not know how to parse it using `sscanf`, as it has 23 elements per line.

Comment: The question [How to use `sscanf()` in loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops) shows how to parse multiple values from a string — the `%n` conversion specifier is a key part of the solution.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan-Leffler. I will use it and get to you with an update,